# Which structure is better for my cms platform

Tags: model-view-controller, architecture

I am designing our cms platform. I meet the question about how combine response data. I know two way solution1 and solution2. Which is better? Why? Anyone have better way.

Solution1:
[image: Solution1]

Solution2:
[image: Solution2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to share the context with us to a definite answer but will the information available I can give you the following.

Solution 1 is tightly coupled entities are in the long run can be a problem but it will be easier to maintain if you have coupled entities in the correct manner.

Solution 2 has a better separation of concerns but you will have to clearly identify entities and will have multiple files to maintain.

Usually a single entity represents a single table in the table with the constraints of the table.